# Not able to use ROWNUM in sql developer

Tags: sql

I was to fetch all the table details through a query which said:

```
select * from student3 where rownum <40;
```

I'm using sql developer for the same, but it is giving an error which says:
Invalid column name 'rownum'

The connection that I'm running this query is MSSQL.

I have also tried using the keywords ROW_NUM, ROW_NUMBER
But still it says invalid column name

So I'm expecting just to limit the number of rows in the query result upto a certain number

Comment: Are you looking for TOP 40...? There is no rownum in SQL Server DB's. That's Oracle-"style".

Comment: Or LIMIT clause?

Comment: SQL Developer and MS SQL Server? Does it work?

Comment: I am surprised, too. AFAIK, Oracle SQL Developer is a tool for the Oracle DBMS only. And yes, `rownum` is Oracle proprietary and numbers the rows matching the rest of the where clause in the order the DBMS happens to fetch them. If MSSQL is supposed to be Microsoft SQL Server (and not Microsoft Access), then the closest match is indeed the `TOP` clause without any `ORDER BY` clause (and applied in a subquery in case of aggregation).

Comment: But beware, as `ROWNUM` was used a long time ago, before Oracle had any limit clause (i.e. long before `FETCH FIRST n ROWS` and also before `ROW_NUMBER`), they allow sorted subqueries in combination with `ROWNUM`: `select * from (select * from students order by name) sorted where rownum <= 5`. For this an approach with `ROW_NUMBER` would be the appropriate solution.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your suggestions, the TOP keyword did the job. Maybe MSSQL doesn't support ROWNUM

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
CREATE TABLE tblSample(
id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
firstName NVARCHAR(50),
grade int
)
INSERT INTO tblSample(firstName,grade) VALUES
('Alex',1),
('Max',2),
('Ram',3),
('Shyam',1),
('Deep',2)

;WITH SampleCTE AS 
(
    select   
             RowNum = row_number() OVER ( order by id ),*
    from     tblSample 

)
SELECT  *
FROM    SampleCTE
WHERE   RowNum < 4

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblSample;
```

[image]

Comment: Far too complicated, just use TOP/LIMIT (depending on the DBMS) with an order by clause.

Comment: @Jonas Metzler: Even an `ORDER BY` clause would be additional work. `TOP`/`LIMIT`/`FETCH FIRST n ROWS` alone would suffice to do what `ROWNUM` usually does. But Oracle allows sorted subqueries with a late `ROWNUM` fillter (which does not comply with standard SQL), in which case the method shown here by Govind would indeed be the equivalent.

Comment: Yes, as the question currently stands, even an order by clause is not required.  But even if it is needed, this should be prefered in my opinion rather than using a windows function and subquery. They are usually a good use case only when a partition is necessary or when the row number itself is important, not the total amount of lines.